# Remove 'product_options' from invoice PDF (magento)

Tags: php, magento, pdf

I want to remove the `product_options` from the invoice PDF. I found where the item is being set (`$this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);` in Invoice.php (line148~)); I tried to change the `product_options` manually using `$item['product_options'] = "";` but this fails to make any change.

Is there a way to do this? What would I need to change to do this? I only need it changing in the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but rather than `$item['product_options'] = "";` try `$item->setProductOptions('');`

Answer (score -1):

I ended up changing this line from: `if ($option['value']) {` to: `if ($option['']) {`